# Interior points and open sets

Tags: analysis, elementary-set-theory

From what I understand, a set is open if every element or point in said set is an interior point.

Now, suppose that I have a set $S$ with infinite points $s_0,s_1,s_k,...$ and so on. Mathematically,
$$S=\{s_0,s_1,s_2,...,s_k\ :k\in\mathbb{N}\}$$

Now, suppose that every point of $S$ is an interior point to a set $T$. Considering the information above, is $T$ an open set?

I would say no. I think that $T$ is open only if $T=S$. We do not know whether $S$ is enough to "cover" $T$. Am I missing something? Is there a situation or theorem that touches on such similar scenario?

I am asking this because I came over a proof that uses a similar argument. I will post it later and link it to this one.

Comment: Well, you're right to say "no", but $T$ need not equal $S$ for $T$ to be (another) open set.  One just has to verify the interior point property for all elements of $T$, i.e. the points of $T$ that are not in $S$.  Example:  Let $S$ be the interval $(0,1)$, and $T=(0,2)$.  Both sets are open, and $T$ contains all the interior points of $S$, but $T\ne S$.

Comment: Oh I should have said $S\supset T$ shouldn't I?

Comment: Well, if $T\subset S$, and $S$ is open, then $T$ can't possibly contain all interior points of $S$, so you're in the vacuous case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider the set $(0,1]$. Now every point other than 1 in the set is an interior point. However, the set itself is not open. So $S=(0,1)$ and $T=(0,1]$. I hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: I am not sure. I would say that your case is disimilar to the one presented. A case that illustrates the question would be a case where every rational and irrational point is an interior point of a set $T$. But $T$ would not be open. For example (in the context of the question) consider a set $S$ which consist of every rational and irrational point in $(0,3)$. Now, let $T$ be the set which consists of every rational and irrational point in $[-1,4]$.Then all elements in $S$ are interior to $T$ but $T$ is not open.

Comment: Or is there something else that I missed?

Comment: If I understand correctly, my $S$ is all the points in the set other than 1. My $T$ is the set given. So $S=(0,1)$ where as $T=(0,1]$ is not open.

Comment: @user97544 Sorry, I worded poorly to begin with.